# Will this work to fix missing source msi issue for repair install?

Tags: windows, winapi, wix, windows-installer

I just have faced notoriously known issue with failed repair/update install of a product when source .msi is missing.
Problem description:

1. Download foo.msi.
2. Run foo.msi.
3. Remove foo.msi.
4. run msiexec.exe /f .

Step #4 fails, however foo.msi is in local Windows Installer cache.
Details: http://www.itninja.com/question/the-msi-doesn-t-repair-when-the-install-source-is-removed-from-its-original-location-how-can-it-be-fixed

I think I have solution for this issue. It is based on altering source location list values using Windows Installer Source Location Manager API at run-time.

I'm planning to create custom action (CA) that will to the following:

1. Create temporary directory.
2. Call `MsiSourceListAddSource()` function passing path to just created temporary directory.
3. Create link to running MSI (value of `DATABASE msi` property) in the temporary directory. If link creation fails, just copy running MSI in the temporary directory.

Schedule this CA before `ResolveSource` action in `InstallExecute` sequence with condition this is not fresh install and not product uninstall.

That is basically it. Also I need another CA that will do clean up after CA #1.

I have working prototype already and it works nice. Questions:

1. Is this the wheel reinventing? Is there already some WiX extension addressing this scenario?
2. Are there any corner cases when `MsiSourceListAddSource()` doesn't work?

Comment: Did your original MSI have embedded CABS or was all the content outside of the MSI?  Also are you trying to repair affected machines as a stand alone action or as part of some future upgrade?

Comment: I'm trying to develop new msi installer, not to fix existing installs. This one will have embedded CABs.